# NullPointerException in the io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doBeginRead

Tags: macos, playframework, netty, osx-yosemite, playframework-2.5

I am using Play 2.5.0-M1 on OSx.

It works good, but on load test it throws an error:

```
play.core.server.NettyServer - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doBeginRead(AbstractNioChannel.java:366) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.beginRead(AbstractChannel.java:683) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.read(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1117) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:614) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:595) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.read(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:614) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:595) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.read(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:95) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:614) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:595) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:86) ~[netty-reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:263) ~[netty-reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.access$200(HandlerPublisher.java:41) ~[netty-reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription$1.run(HandlerPublisher.java:441) ~[netty-reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

This is no the problem of "50" simultaneous connection on mac with netty because it throw even with 10 connection. The load test was:

```
ab -n 500 -c 10 http://localhost:9000/
```

Does someone see this error on previous versions of play ?

Do you have suggestion why this error thrown and how to fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'It works good'? What are the differences of your normal run compared to a test run? Do you use a different config? I never had this exception when I did load tests so far.

Comment: 'it works well' means no errors. I use the same config.